# can i capture audio output from android system in shared library that will be built inside aosp source tree

Tags: android, android-source

I need to capture all audio output from a shared library written in native code in **AOSP** source tree, and i will build this library to generate **'.so'** file. This library is considered injected module inside **AOSP** and has access to some system classes such as '**AudioSystem**'.

I'm trying to find a way for this library to capture **audio output** by capturing **audio buffers** from '**audioflinger**' or any other component that i can access?

I dont know so far which other classes or components i have access to, and which one of them can lead me to capture the buffers.

i manage to do those import in **c++**, but then didnt know what functions i can use or do i need to import something else

```
#include <media/IAudioFlinger.h>
#include <media/IAudioFlingerClient.h>
#include <system/audio.h>
#include <media/AudioSystem.h>
#include <media/AudioTrack.h>
#include <media/AudioRecord.h>
#include <audio_utils/fifo.h>
```